# Filter Records by Date

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to create a simple visualforce form which filters a second visualforce page of notes by date, rendered as a pdf.  The pdf is rendering, but the dates from my first form are having no effect.  I'm trying to use on controller so I can use the start and end date value (currently fields on my custom object RIS_Case_Notes) on my first form to filter the second.  Currently I'm getting the entire list of case notes rather than a filtered list by date.

Initial form:

```
<apex:page standardController="AECaseMgmt__Program_Case__c" extensions="CaseNoteFIltered_extn">

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="Select Case Note Filters">
  <apex:pageMessages /> <!-- this is where the error messages will appear -->

    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!casenote.FromDate__c}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!casenote.EndDate__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Generate" action="{!generate}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>    

    </apex:pageBlockButtons>      
</apex:pageBlock>
```

PDF Visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="AECaseMgmt__Program_Case__c" renderAs="PDF" sidebar="false" extensions="CaseNoteFiltered_extn"
                                       showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<head>
  <style>
     @page { 
  size:{'8.5in 11in')}; 
  margin: 5mm;}


  .no-border {
  border: none
  }

  .bottom-border {
  border-bottom: solid black;
  border-width: thin;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 1px;
  }

  .border-full{
  border: solid 1px black;text-align: center; border="1"
  }

  .top-border {
  border-top: solid black;
  border-width: thin;
  }

table, th, td {
    padding: 1px;
    font-size: 11px;    
}


    </style>

</head>
<body>



<table style = "font-weight: bold; ">

    <tr>
        <td >
            Family: <apex:outputText value="{!AECaseMgmt__Program_Case__c.AECaseMgmt__Household__r.name}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            Case #: <apex:outputText value="{!AECaseMgmt__Program_Case__c.RIS_Case_Text_only__c}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<table >
    <apex:repeat value="{!casenotelist}" var="casenote"> 
        <br/> 
        <tr>
             <td  style = "width: 500px" >Date: <apex:outputfield value="{!casenote.Date_of_Service__c}"/> </td>
             <td style = "width: 500px" > Category:  <apex:outputfield value="{!casenote.Category__c}"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>Entered by: <apex:outputfield value="{!casenote.Entered_By_User__r.Full_Name__c}"/> </td>
                <td > Case Member (if applicable): <apex:outputfield value="{!casenote.Case_Member__c}"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <br/>
        <tr>
                <td style = "width: 1000px" colspan = "2" class = "bottom-border" >Case Note: <apex:outputfield value="{!casenote.Case_Note__c}"/> </td>
                </tr>
            <br/>
            </apex:repeat>
   </table>     

  </body>
```

Controller Extension (where I assume my problem is):

```
public class CaseNoteFIltered_extn {
public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}
public list <RIS_Case_Note__c> casenotelist {get; set;}
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public RIS_Case_Note__c casenote {get;set;}
public CaseNoteFiltered_extn(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    stdCntrlr = controller;
    casenote = new RIS_Case_Note__c();
    if (casenotelist==null){
        casenotelist = new List <RIS_Case_Note__c>();
        }
    currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');      

    casenotelist = [Select ID, Date_of_Service__c, Case_Note__c,Category__c, Case_Number__c, Entered_By_User__r.Full_Name__c,
                    Case_Member__c
                   from RIS_Case_Note__c 
                   Where Case_Number__c =: controller.getId() AND
                    Date_of_Service__c >=: casenote.FromDate__c AND
                    Date_of_Service__c <=: casenote.EndDate__c 
                   ORDER BY Date_of_Service__c  ASC];  

}
public PageReference generate() {
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/case_Notepdf?&id=' + currentRecordId  );

    return (pageRef);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some of your confusion comes from re-using the same extension for both pages, but when you load the second page, it loads its own instance of the extension class, without any of the values from the first page. You need to pass the values along to your second page through another method.

Your query depends on a object `casenote`, but it only appears in one location, where you define it as an empty record:

```
casenote = new RIS_Case_Note__c();
```

You already use the id in the pages parameters, why not pass your dates along as well?

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/case_Notepdf?&id=' 
+ currentRecordId + '&StartDate=' + startDate.format() + '&EndDate=' + endDate.format());
```

Then, in your constructor, you can pull the date values from your parameters, assign them to your `casenote`, and then filter your query based on the values in the `casenote`, without having to change much code.

```
casenote = new RIS_Case_Note__c(
    End_Date__c = Date.parse(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('EndDate'))
);
```